# google map changing center when zoom in ios sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a ios app where I zoom in google map to certain zoom level programatically, but when I do so map changes its center. I want to be able to zoom in with keeping current center as center.
Can anybody help me.

Code below:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:18.5600
                                                        longitude:73.7903
                                                             zoom:12];

mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mapView_.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
mapView_.delegate = self;
mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
mapView_.padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 20, 0);
mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid;
self.view = mapView_;
```

This is how I add the map.

And then on certain event I zoom it to zoom level 14:

```
camera=[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon zoom:14];
   [mapView_ setCamera:camera];
```

Comment: You probably need to provide some code in order to determine the problem.

Comment: @PCLuddite  code added.

Comment: Do you found how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but hopefully help someone with similar issue in the future.

You should set `allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom` of your `GMSMapView` object's `settings` to `false`. This will disable any other gestures on GMSMapView when you zoom or rotate.

`settings` here is `GMSUISettings` class which is responsible for all user interface settings of the map.

```
mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = false
```

Comment: But in my case (Maps 2.7.0) this still changes the center location :-( I cannot scroll thats true but the camera target position updates. Some way to prevent this?